# Jstree fails after postback

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jstree

I'm using the Jstree to generate a tree stucture in my MVC3 project.

It works ok on load, but when an postback/submit happens the tree will not render.
It simple shows the list in "normal" Ul/li fashion.

From what I can tell the classes that Jstree normalle attach to the Ul/Li is not attached after postback.

My Jquery is like this.. very basic

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#testTree").bind("loaded.jstree", function(event, data) {

    }).jstree({
        themes: {
            theme: "default",
            dots: false,
            icons: false
        },
        core: {
            animation: 200,
            open_parents: false
        },
        cookies: {
            cookie_options: {
                path: '/'
            }
        },
        plugins: ["themes", "html_data", "cookies"]
    });
});
```

It appears that the problem only happens when I have the jquery.mobile 1.2 (http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js") on the page.
If I remove this all is working ok.

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: Postback happens when I use a submit butten in an html form

Comment: In that case I don't understand you question. Could you try to explain it to me again?

Comment: @Radek - Sure I will try explain in more detail

Comment: The JStree loads fine the first time the page is loaded(comming from another page via link). If I use a submit button on the page(to search) the page postback and shows the results from search in an partial view on the same page. This time the JStree will not render and it looks like the script do not fire.
If I set the this in the layout page all is ok. 
    $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
     });
This leads me to think it has something to with Jquery mobile and the way it calls scripts

Hope this clears things up.

Comment: So you display the search results somewhere else than the original tree? You didn't mention in your question that this is mobile version of your site. I have no experience with mobile version nor displaying search results somewhere else. I just let jsTree handle it.

Comment: @Radek The tree remains the same after the search.
It is a organisation search and the tree just allow users to navigate the tree instead of seaching.
The result and search box is in one partial view and the tree in another partial view.

Comment: Can you try and provide working jsfiddle?

Comment: @Radek don't normally use jsfidler but here is a sample
http://jsfiddle.net/bg2yZ/3/
This is only from the partial view that renders the tree.
Do you need more?